# How beans xml are merged?

Tags: java, maven, cdi

Suppose I have a project with CDI and beans.xml that have dependency to secondary project that is packaged in some.jar file. In some.jar there is beans.xml too. How they merged after I compile and deploy the main project (in war file)? Can I write only one xml for main project or I **must** have several separate beans.xml for main and secondary projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html) each module, jar or war that contains CDI beans in WEB-INF/classes should have beans.xml in order to be processed. 
No, you cannot write only one xml for the main project (if by project you mean a war) and by secondary projects you mean jar modules.